# Is it possible in this Universe to communicate a bit of information with energy that scales sub-linearly with distance?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, information

If we look at all the ways that people do communicate information, they all seem to have a cost "at least linear in distance." For example, communicating over a wire has attenutation, so the energy cost is "worse than linear." There are other proposed methods, for example, communicating using inscribed matter over the vacuum of space, as proposed by Rose et. al. in "Inscribed matter as an energy-efficient means of communication with an extraterrestrial civilization."

It is implied by this work that accelerating some kind of spaceship and pointing it in some direction would result in this spaceship "travelling forever" until it reaches the destination, so at first glace it appears that this technique would overcome the "linear in distance" energy cost of communication. However, outer space is not a "perfect vacuum." (See this link http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2000/DaWeiCai.shtml where different sources are gathered suggesting that the density of outer space is somewhere around 0.06 to 1000 particle per cubic centimeter, the key point being not 0!) This means that some frictional forces, no matter how small, still exist and to project a spaceship twice the distance, in the limit of long distances would still require twice the energy. This seems to also imply that electromagnetic radiation would attenuate at least a little bit.

It also seems like creating a perfect vacuum may be impossible due to the Casimir effect (where even in a vacuum "virtual particles" spring into existence. Would the existence of such virtual particles cause frictional effects if you were trying to move something through it? Would it cause some attenuation of an electromagnetic signal (no matter how small).

Does the Casimir effect suggest that "the energy cost of communicating a bit is linear in distance" is a law of the Universe? Can anyone think of any way at all (no matter how outlandish or impractical) that could be used to overcome this cost?

One possibility seems to be communicating through an Einstein Rosen Bridge (aka wormhole), but I am not a physicist so I don't know if the energy cost of maintaining a wormhole would be proportional to distance. On the other hand, that is definitely an enormous practical issue, but my question is about the laws of physics.